# d3 area chart using JSON object

Tags: json, d3.js

I am building a d3 area chart by following the example code posted at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195  . However in my program, data is stored in JSON format inside a variable (Object). Need assistance in replacing the lines below.

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
 data.forEach(function(d) {
 d.date = parseDate(d.date);
 d.close = +d.close;
});
```

Tried data.push([parseDate(jvariable.time),jvariable.total]). Not working. Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: So you are using the [d3.json](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json) function?  Also, it would be helpful to see your data format.

Comment: can you give an example of your data object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to remove the d3.tsv file loader and use your variable directly. So you just need to rename your object to data and use it following the example I created here

http://bl.ocks.org/mohamed-ali/ed4772df6dca7a48f678

basically, the solution is instead of using:

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
 data.forEach(function(d) {
 d.date = parseDate(d.date);
 d.close = +d.close;
});
```

use

```
 data = {...data object...}

 data.forEach(function(d) {
   d.date = parseDate(d.date);
   d.close = +d.close;
 });
```